# Which sentence is better? "Sites no longer use..." or "sites not use anymore..."?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, grammaticality, sentence-choice

Which sentence is correct? If neither is correct, what should be the correct sentence?

> - These sites no longer use the "###check-also-box" widget.
> - These sites not use anymore the "###check-also-box" widget.

Comment: As @Aidan answers, the first is better. If the reader is a user and not a programmer I would delete the word "widget".

Comment: Not an answer by itself, but when in doubt, prefer the shortest grammatically correct form that unambiguously conveys your intended meaning. In English (and a significant majority of other languages for that matter), that will almost always be the idiomatic form, with the only major exceptions being idiomatic fixed phrases.

Comment: "These sites not use anymore" isn't even English.

Comment: x no longer use y OR x do not use y any longer.

Comment: Why is this closed as off-topic?  Word choice is very much on-topic. https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 20):

The first sentence is good.

If you want to use 'any more' then it is more natural (at least to me!) at the end: 'These sites do not use the "###check-also-box" widget any more.'  But I prefer the first sentence.

Comment: You can also say "don't" instead of "do not", if you want.

Comment: @user253751 You can do, but this is technical writing. In such a context it would come across as a bit unprofessional and dancing-paperclippy.

Answer (score 13):

The first is correct and good.

The second is grammatically incorrect.

1. "anymore" should be "any more".
2. "any more" should go at the end.
3. There is a missing word "do".

Hence we have:

- "These sites do not use the "###check-also-box" widget any more."

However, the first sentence is (in my opinion) better than the second, because it is shorter. In technical writing, it is often better to be brief, as long as you do not compromise accuracy and completeness.

EDIT: Whether to use "anymore" or "any more" is apparently stylistic. My preference is for "any more" but it may be the case that "anymore" is not incorrect.

Comment: Re 1: From [Definition of Anymore by Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anymore#usage-1): "Although both *anymore* and *any more* are found in written use, in current writing *anymore* is the more common styling."  I guess this is a regional issue.

Comment: @L.F. Yes, there are plenty of stylings that have become common which I learned at school were technically incorrect. I need to learn that rules are for the old-fashioned and pedantic. :-)

Comment: @L.F. The Oxford online UK English dictionary (Lexico) gives "any more (North American anymore)" and does not list "anymore" as a word. The Oxford online US English dictionary gives "anymore (also any more)" but does not have an entry for "any more" or list the phrase under "any" or "more".

Comment: @PrimeMover In many ways US English is more old-fashioned than British English (e.g. verb forms like "gotten" died out centuries ago in British English).

Comment: @alephzero IMO the language which Americans call "English" should really be called "American" because English it is not. But no, American for "American" is "English", and that's where we stand.

Comment: @PrimeMover I don't know about the vocabulary/grammar, but the American accent is closer to the shared accent from colonial times; the modern British accent came later (perhaps as a way to distinguish themselves). Period/time-travel movies and TV shows generally get this backwards.

Comment: @Barmar A shallow cultural imperialist may suggest that this is because British English has evolved more, and is therefore "more modern" than the American version. :-) I can't speak for movies and TV shows except to express amusement at the general inaccuracy of the American view of Britain.

Comment: @PrimeMover The recent example is the "Sleepy Hollow" TV show. The main character is Ichabod Crane, who has time traveled from the revolutionary era. He speaks with a modern British accent, because Americans assume that's how we spoke when we were a British colony.

Comment: @Barmar I steer clear of such appalling abhominations as a matter of course, so it is highly unlikely I'll experience it.

Comment: @PrimeMover It was just an example, but I think practically every movie or TV show I've seen about the revolution has the founding fathers speaking with a British accent.

Comment: @PrimeMover “This is abhominable—which he would call abominable.”

Comment: @Barmar I wonder if the recent fashion to perform Shakespeare with pronunciation as close to the original as possible will make it into pop culture. It’s not actually the same as an Appalachian accent, and the court of George III would not sound exactly like people in the southeastern US, but that’s what they would remind us of today.

Comment: @Barmar [This source claims](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/hjmar4/george_iii_and_george_washington_would_they_have/) that upper-class Londoners were already dropping R’s by the 1770s, and probably lengthening their A’s, that New Englanders like John Adams would probably pahk their cahts in Hahvahd Yahd by then too, and that George Washington, who’d had elocution lessons growing up to sound like a proper English gentleman but was said by contemporaries to still sound somewhat American, probably did the same but with different vowels.

Comment: @Barmar There are already some attested examples of British and American vocabulary diverging by then, such as when an American governor told George III that his American subjects make bread from corn instead of wheat, the King got confused and asked, which corn, and the American told him that he meant “Indian corn” or maize.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm far from being a native speaker. But here are two websites which indicate "anymore" (one word) as the correct form in this case: [Online Writing Training](https://onlinewritingtraining.com.au/anymore-versus-any-more/), [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/anymore-vs-any-more/). But I'm not sure how reliable they are. There are also questions here on Stack Exchange: [anymore vs any more](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31167/anymore-vs-any-more)

Answer (score 1):

"not use" is incorrect because "not" does not go before a verb. "use not" would be more grammatically correct, but would still not be standard English, because in standard English, only auxiliary verbs can be directly negated (in nonstandard or archaic English, you may see non-auxiliary verbs being directly negated). Since "use" is not an auxiliary verb, the dummy auxiliary verb "do" is added, giving "do not use".

Answer (score 0):

As in other answers, the first sentence is standard/correct (apart from issues about "anymore" versus "any more").

People have asserted that the second sentence is "ungrammatical", and I agree that it "sounds wrong" (to a native U.S. English speaker...).

But to understand *why* it is "wrong" (from the perspective of a person whose first language is other than English... and I myself am acquainted a bit with French and Germa, also having studied Latin in school...), it *is* odd that the negation of "These sites use X." is not "These sites not use X." (or some other word order. Instead, the emphatic "do" is somehow required for the negation! It is ok for the positive assertion "These sites do use X.", though it does add emphasis. But, again, the negation without the emphatic "do" is incorrect?!? :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support - for some reason, in English, "not" can only follow auxiliary verbs and "to be" (is/are/am/...) - otherwise, you must add "do" (which is an auxiliary verb). Every English speaker must know this but it is certainly strange when compared to other languages. Even when the word "do" is used as a main verb, it cannot be negated directly, but requires an auxiliary "do" - e.g. "do not do this"

Comment: Exception that tests the rule: Yoda in *The Empire Strikes Back* breaks this rule and uses many other strange but technically-grammatical constructions, to show that he’s exotic, and to force the audience to think about what he says.

Comment: Word order is also much freer in English poetry, especially early-modern poetry.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence, as others have said, is fine.

For the second sentence, I don't think anyone emphasized sufficiently that you *must* put the word "do" before "not". That is required to make it grammatical. It is also rare to have "anymore" before the verb. So this is perfectly fine:

> These sites do not use the ###check-also-box widget any more.

Now a couple of comments about formality. This sentence has a slightly more informal sound. It's still OK for formal writing - it's a mistake to think that "formal writing" and "informal writing" are totally different things. But this sentence is the way you would very often say it out loud, only then you would use a contraction. And also, the newer, now more common spelling "anymore" would probably be better, so you have:

> These sites don't use the ###check-also-box widget anymore.

Be aware that extremely high avoidance of informality is not always the best even for technical writing. Your first sentence with "no longer use" is not excessively formal, and this last sentence with "don't use" is not too terribly informal. So both can work in lots of written contexts - your choice.